# How to find Number of null column in table using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A database has a lot of columns (more than 100). Some of these columns have null entries. How can I find out how many columns have null entries in at least one row, without manually testing each and every column?

Comment: Do want to check for each row in the table, how many columns are null or do you want to know which columns of the table contains ONLY null values in all rows?

Comment: or how many of the columns CAN contain null? More detail please..

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth  i wanna check how many columns are null in that table

Comment: it might happen like some link was missing for that column and it took null value insted of a value.. so how to identify those column

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. Can you provide an example? What's the table like, what is it you're looking for in that table, and what should the result look like? I'm guessing you have a table with 100 columns and you want to add a check `col1 is null or col2 is null or ... or coln is null`

Comment: suppose we are having a table called EMP and there are 100 column in that table...but while populating data in EMP table it migh happen some of the column will populate null value (may be data issue or some other issue) so how to identify the number of column in that emp table which was null as value..(like column-23 is geting complete null value so how to identify column-23)

Comment: @subrat: Please edit your question and add that additional info there.

Comment: @subrat: Suppose you have a table called EMP and it has 500 rows and the column JOB has a value in 499 rows but is NULL in 1 row.  Do you call that a "null column"?

Comment: @TONY thanks for ur view but i want all the rows to be null not some are null and some are having value

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  for col in (select table_name, column_name 
              from user_tab_columns where table_name='EMP')
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||col.table_name
                      ||' where '||col.column_name
                      ||' is not null and rownum=1'
      into l_count;
    if l_count = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line ('Column '||col.column_name||' contains only nulls');
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **analyzing** your table (compute statistics, don't estimate) and then (immediately) do:

```
select column_name, num_nulls
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'SOME_TABLENAME'
and owner = 'SOME_OWNER';
```

Of course as data later changes, this will become slightly more incorrect.  If you need to get more fancy and do a field population count (fieldpop), then you'll need to loop through all rows and check for nulls explicitly (and exclude any other values you deem "not populated", perhaps a default of 0 for a number field for example).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the direction in which to research:

Check "user_tab_columns" through which you can get information related to columns in a table.
E.g.

```
select count(*) from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'YOURTABLENAME'
```

This gives you the number of columns in that table.

Together with this you would need to use a cursor, i think, to check each column for null values rather than adding a null check in WHERE clause for each column.

Comment: @ LUKAS ok so we want to CHECK for each column ... what about if we have 500 column

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of NULL column values per row of data:

```
declare
  TYPE refc IS REF CURSOR; 
  col_cv refc; 
  l_query varchar(3999);
  v_rownum number;
  v_count number;
begin
  l_query := 'select rownum, ';
  for col in (select table_name, column_name 
              from user_tab_columns where table_name='EMP')
  loop
    l_query := l_query ||'DECODE('||col.column_name||',NULL,1,0)+';  
  end loop;
  l_query := l_query||'+0 as no_of_null_values from EMP';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);

OPEN col_cv FOR l_query;
LOOP
FETCH col_cv into v_rownum, v_count;
EXIT WHEN col_cv%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rownum || ' ' || v_count);

END LOOP;
CLOSE col_cv;

end;
```

I feel dirty even writing it! (It won't work when the number of columns in the table is very large and l_query overflows).

You just need to change the table name (EMP above).